# mysqli select does not return variables

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I am trying to make a simple select query with mysqli but it seems like it does not work. Does anyone see what is wrong here? I expect the two variables being printed out at the end of the file.

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("select billnumber, amount from bill where billid = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('i', $id);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($billnumber, $amount);
$stmt->fetch();

var_dump($mysqli);
echo "<br><br>";

var_dump($stmt);
echo "<br>";

echo $billnumber;
echo $amount;

$stmt->close();
```

Output:

```
object(mysqli)#2 (19) { ["affected_rows"]=> int(-1) ["client_info"]=> string(79) "mysqlnd 5.0.11-dev - 20120503 - $Id: bf9ad53b11c9a57efdb1057292d73b928b8c5c77 $" ["client_version"]=> int(50011) ["connect_errno"]=> int(0) ["connect_error"]=> NULL ["errno"]=> int(0) ["error"]=> string(0) "" ["error_list"]=> array(0) { } ["field_count"]=> int(2) ["host_info"]=> string(25) "Localhost via UNIX socket" ["info"]=> NULL ["insert_id"]=> int(0) ["server_info"]=> string(6) "5.5.28" ["server_version"]=> int(50528) ["stat"]=> string(152) "Uptime: 2619401 Threads: 11 Questions: 220513466 Slow queries: 146 Opens: 14454832 Flush tables: 1 Open tables: 64 Queries per second avg: 84.184" ["sqlstate"]=> string(5) "00000" ["protocol_version"]=> int(10) ["thread_id"]=> int(3244658) ["warning_count"]=> int(0) } 

object(mysqli_stmt)#4 (10) { ["affected_rows"]=> NULL ["insert_id"]=> NULL ["num_rows"]=> NULL ["param_count"]=> NULL ["field_count"]=> NULL ["errno"]=> NULL ["error"]=> NULL ["error_list"]=> NULL ["sqlstate"]=> NULL ["id"]=> NULL }
```

Comment: `var_dump($stmt)` shows all null values because you called `$stmt->close()`, which discards all the information in the statement.

Comment: Are you sure you gave a valid `billid` in the query

Comment: Yes the $id is valid.

Comment: Looking at the PHP docs for this might actually help...
http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` if you're not already doing so.

Comment: It does not show any errors.

Comment: Error catching script (condensed):
`$stmt = $mysqli->prepare(); echo "Prepare error? ".$mysqli->error; $stmt->bind_param(); if (!$stmt->execute()) echo "Execute error? ".$stmt->error; $stmt->bind_result(); while ($stmt->fetch) { echo $amount . $billnumber; }` Should catch all the likely places for errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mysqli_stmt_close()

> Closes a prepared statement. mysqli_stmt_close() also deallocates the
>   statement handle. If the current statement has pending or unread
>   results, this function cancels them so that the next query can be
>   executed.

You shouldn't close before your read the results

Comment: I moved stmt_close() to the end but I still do not have any results.

Comment: now var_dump($stmt); should return something different. Can you update your post to include it.
Go to php man and check all methods return too

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("select billnumber, amount from bill where billid = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('i', $id);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($billnumber, $amount);
while($stmt -> fetch()){

var_dump($billnumber);
echo "<br><br>";

var_dump($amount);
echo "<br>";

echo $billnumber;
echo $amount;
}
$stmt->close();
```

Let me know if it works  :)